# Button Placement on split screen design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im playing around with bootstrap and i've come up against something I am struggling to find an answer to.

I want to put a 'Login' on the bottom right of the screen, near the fold. Below is my code:

```css
img{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-40%);
    z-index: 2;
}


.leftside, .rightside {

    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;

}

@media screen and (min-width:768px)

{
    .leftside, .rightside {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
.leftside {

    background:#20639B;

}

.rightside {

}
.home-btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="Bird.png" alt="hummingbird">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
            <div class="leftside">

            </div>



        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
            <div class="rightside d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <h2>Mini Blog Project</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary float-right home-btn">Login</button>
            </div>
            

        </div>


    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the button sits centred on the right box, which is my second option. My first would be to have it sit within the right panel, near the bottom right. If I move the button outiside of the right div, i can make the button go down to the right, but it adds a row that breaks the effect.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wait is it "bottom-left" or "bottom-right"? and you have 2 sections where you want the button to be placed? and did you try using `absolute`?

Comment: what is the 'Right Panel'?

Comment: in the div class rightside

Comment: and the "Bottom Right" ?

Comment: yeah, so, if you render it, you can see the login putton sits below the <p>, what i want to do is push it down and out to the right, so it would sit in the corner right side of your screen,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
img{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-40%);
    z-index: 2;
}


.leftside, .rightside {

    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;

}

@media screen and (min-width:768px)

{
    .leftside, .rightside {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
.leftside {

    background:#20639B;

}

.rightside {
 position: relative;
}
.home-btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="Bird.png" alt="hummingbird">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
            <div class="leftside">

            </div>



        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
            <div class="rightside d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <h2>Mini Blog Project</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary float-right home-btn">Login</button>
            </div>
            

        </div>


    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what did you change? other than the transform?

Comment: i deleted  bottom: 40%; left: 50%; transform:translateX(-50%); and add  bottom: 20px; right: 20px; to .home.btn.